# Haskell: Common pattern to deal with Failure inside IO :: IO (Either String Int)

Tags: haskell, monads

Trying to understand the pattern used to deal with possible failures inside `IO`. If its just one `case`s like below, its probably acceptable, but if the nesting goes on for a bunch of nested `IO (Either String Int)`s is there a common pattern to handle such types. For instance, if `b` in `functionDoSomething` is again a `(Either a b)` and fetching value on success and doing something with it again will be another such `case`. Is there a higher order function that I can use? I'm not comfortable with monad transformers yet, not sure if they can be used to deal with this specific monad stack. If they can be used here, is there a way to do it without using them.

```
import Control.Monad

functionCreate :: Int -> IO (Either String Int)
functionDoSomething :: Int -> IO b

functionUse :: IO ()
functionUse = do
   created <- functionCreate 10
   case created of
      (Right v)        -> void $ functionDoSomething v
      _                -> return ()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I understand that you're new to Haskell, and that monad transformers aren't the first concept you'd want to grapple with. In a situation like this, it *is*, however, the pattern to use.

Monads in general enable you to 'weave in and out of functors', so to speak. Had you only had `Either`, you could have used the `Either` values with `do` notation to pull the `Right` values out of the values, while short-circuiting the `Left` cases.

In this case, however, you have a 'stack' of monads: `Either` inside of `IO`. Thus, when you attempt to use `do` notation, you're in the `IO` context, and that means that, as the OP illustrates, the values that you 'pull out of' the functions, using the `<-` arrow, are still `Either` values.

Monad transformers enable you to treat stacks of monads (like, in this case `Either` values inside of `IO`) as `Monad` instances, so that you can, e.g., use `do` notation on the stack.

While you'd expect the `Either` monad transformer to be called `EitherT`, it is, for various reasons, called `ExceptT`. You could simplify the OP code slightly like this:

```
import Control.Monad (void)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except

functionUse :: IO (Either String ())
functionUse = runExceptT $ do
  created <- ExceptT $ functionCreate 10
  liftIO $ void $ functionDoSomething created
```

Here, `created` is an `Int` value, which can then be passed to `functionDoSomething`.

Comment: `IO (Either String ())` is also `ExceptT String IO ()`, right?

Comment: @chepner They're two different types, but they're isomorphic. `ExceptT` goes the one way, and `runExceptT` goes the other way.

Comment: @chepner `ExceptT`is a `newtype`, so in a sense you're right.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see.